# Function called on interval accesses global variable

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I am asynchronously receiving data (from 0 to 100 points per second) that is passed to a high-startup-cost function, extendTraces(data), which updates the user interface. If I call extendTraces() upon generating every point, the user interface becomes unresponsive. I've found that it is much more efficient to call the function periodically and pass it an array of points, call it pointArray.

I can track how many points have been added to pointArray and call extendTraces(pointArray) every 20th addition:

```
//inside asynchronous function
pointArray.push(point);
if (this.pointArray.length == 20){
    (<any>Plotly).extendTraces(this.pointArray);
    this.resetPointArray();
}
```

But if I fill pointArray halfway and don't receive any data for a while, I'd also to call extendTraces.

My solution is to call extendTraces() every second

```
//inside a function that is called when the page loads
window.setInterval(function() {
    if (pointArray.length > 0){
        (<any>Plotly).extendTraces(this.pointArray);
        this.resetPointArray();
    }
}, 1000);
```

My function that receives the points will simply concatenate them onto the pointArray.

```
//inside asynchronous function
pointArray.push(point);
```

I am new to js and was wondering if I'm using the correct paradigms for this task. I see a lot of information about callbacks and promises which I don't fully understand but I am suspicious that I'm doing something wrong by not using them. Coming from c++, I am concerned that two functions, the function defined in setInterval and the asynchronous function that receives points, both have access to the pointArray without any hardcoded mutex.

Comment: what it the question? there is no question.

Comment: This is opinion-based question. If your code works and is maintainable, to you or your team, then it doesn't matter what someone else thinks how you accomplished the task.

Comment: I am wondering about the correct pattern for periodically calling a function that depends on an asynchronously updated variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be tempted to wrap the logic into its own class, where it simply allows you to specify

- After how many adds to call the method
- After how long of inactivity to call the method
- the method to call

```js
function PointHandler(flushSize, flushTime, flushCallback){
 
  var pointArray = [];
  var lastFlush = setTimeout(() => this.flush(),flushTime)
  
  this.addPoint = function(point){
      pointArray.push(point);
      if(pointArray.length == flushSize){
          this.flush();          
      }
      clearTimeout(lastFlush)
      lastFlush = setTimeout(() => this.flush(), flushTime);
  }
  
  this.flush = function(){
      flushCallback(pointArray);
      pointArray = [];
      clearTimeout(lastFlush)
      lastFlush = setTimeout(() => this.flush(), flushTime);
  }

}

var handler = new PointHandler(10, 5000, points => console.log(points));

document.getElementById("clickme").addEventListener("click", () => handler.addPoint(new Date()));
```

```html
<button id="clickme">Add point</button>
```

The above code will call the callback after 5 seconds of inactivity, or when it gets 10 points added.

My callback simply `console.log` the current points, but you could call your method.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a debounce function, this basically limits how often the function can be called. Here is the debounce function from the underscore library:

```js
// Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
// be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
// N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
// leading edge, instead of the trailing.
_.debounce = function(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout, result;

  var later = function(context, args) {
    timeout = null;
    if (args) result = func.apply(context, args);
  };

  var debounced = restArguments(function(args) {
    if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    if (immediate) {
      var callNow = !timeout;
      timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
      if (callNow) result = func.apply(this, args);
    } else {
      timeout = _.delay(later, wait, this, args);
    }

    return result;
  });

  debounced.cancel = function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = null;
  };

  return debounced;
};
```

Now just wrap your extendTraces function around the debounce function and then call the function that is return from it.

Source: https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L887-L914